# Eigen::Matrix<double,4,4> to Eigen::Quaterniond

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen3

```
Eigen::Matrix4d transformation_matrix; //assume this is initialized
Eigen::Matrix4d &matrix = transformation_matrix;   
Eigen::Quaterniond quat;
quat(matrix);
```

I am trying to find a rotation matrix from a transformation matrix. There is already an API in `Eigen::Quaterniond` library `toRotationMatrix`. But to use this, I need a 4x4 `Quaterniond` (Please correct, if this is wrong).

Getting compilation error as

```
error: no match for call to ‘(Eigen::Quaterniond {aka Eigen::Quaternion<double>}) (const Matrix4d&)’
```

Please help.
[Followed this link for conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761909/eigen-convert-matrix3d-rotation-to-quaternion?rq=1)

```
Eigen::Quaterniond quat;
quat(matrix);
```

When initializing `Quaterniond` , I am getting a different error :

```
Eigen::internal::quaternionbase_assign_impl<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, 4, 4>’ used in nested name specifier
   internal::quaternionbase_assign_impl<MatrixDerived>::run(*this, xpr.derived());
```

Comment: you need to edit the question title to be more informative.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing here:

```cpp
Eigen::Quaterniond quat;
quat(matrix);
```

is creating a quaternion and then calling it's `operator()` with a matrix. But as far as I can see, the Quaternion does not even have an `operator()` for anything: [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1QuaternionBase.html)

Take a look at the first answer of ggael in the [question you referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761909/eigen-convert-matrix3d-rotation-to-quaternion?rq=1). You can either use the constructor of the quaternion:

```cpp
Eigen::Quaterniond quat(matrix);
```

or it's assignment operator:

```cpp
Eigen::Quaterniond quat;
quat = matrix;
```

Both are defined for a matrix. However, I can't tell you, if they work for 4x4 matrices. If not extract the 3x3 rotation part of the matrix.

**Edit:**

After a quick test on my computer, you can't pass a 4x4 matrix to a quaternion. Either use a `Eigen::Matrix3d` instead or do something like this:

```cpp
Eigen::Quaterniond quat(matrix.topLeftCorner<3, 3>());
```

**Edit 2:**

> I am trying to find a rotation matrix from a transformation matrix. There is already an API in Eigen::Quaterniond library toRotationMatrix. But to use this, I need a 4x4 Quaterniond (Please correct, if this is wrong).

Well, this isn't really correct. A rotation matrix can be converted into a quaternion and a quaternion into a rotation matrix. In a 4x4 matrix, the rotation part is contained inside the top-left 3x3 submatrix. However, in a general transformation matrix, this part isn't necessarily only the rotation. It can also contain other transformations like scaling. In this case, I am not sure, if you can transform it directly into a quaternion without extracting the rotational part first. I doubt it, but I am not sure about this. However, if you have a general transformation matrix, you can test if the upper 3x3 part is a pure rotation by calculating its determinant. If it is 1, you have a pure rotation. If this is not the case, take a look at [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/given-this-transformation-matrix-how-do-i-decompose-it-into-translation-rotati) to calculate the rotational part.
If your goal is to extract just the rotation of a 4x4 matrix, you do not need quaternions at all. Rotation matrices and quaternions are just different representations of the same thing.

Comment: Corrected the initialization.
on doing this 
Eigen::Quaterniond quat; 
quat(matrix);

I am getting a different error
Eigen::internal::quaternionbase_assign_impl<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, 4, 4>’ used in nested name specifier
   internal::quaternionbase_assign_impl<MatrixDerived>::run(*this, xpr.derived());

Comment: Have a look at my edit. The error is related to the fact, that 4x4 matrices are not supported. Extract the rotation part as shown in the edit.

Comment: Watch out, there was a mistake since I wrote my answer from another computer than the one I tested the code. Now the edit should be fine.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer . I am able to convert matrix to Quaternion. yes, you are right. I wanted to get rotation matrix but it is with scaling factor due to which I am not getting proper results. The link which you have mentioned it's quite good but I am unable to understand it. It will be great if you can share some other links or code related to this.

Comment: The answer provided by "imallett" in the link is as simple as it can be. Don't know how to explain it better. I have no clue what you are struggling with, but maybe this link might help you: https://www.brainvoyager.com/bv/doc/UsersGuide/CoordsAndTransforms/SpatialTransformationMatrices.html - it explains how a 4x4 transformation matrix for 3d space is composed and why. After reading and understanding this, revisit the link in my answer. It should be much clearer then.